# Async Socket Server Listen Again

Tags: android, .net, sockets, asynchronous, server

I am using the sample from Microsoft's Async Socket Listener. I got everything working fine, I am able to send files and data etc. However, I am struggling with trying to keep the socket open. I do not want to close the socket and re-open for every file I am sending. I want to keep it open until all files are sent. I assume the issue is in the 'SendCallback' but I can not seem to get it to work.

.Net Code

```
 Private Shared Sub SendCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        ' Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        Dim handler As Socket = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)

        ' Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
        Dim bytesSent As Integer = handler.EndSend(ar)


        'trying to receive again - I added this after commenting out the below lines but am missing something.
        Dim state As StateObject = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadCallback), state)


        'The below lines are what was there, I tried to comment out and use the above lines trying to receive again but it does not work. I assume I am missing something simple but can not find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

        'handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
        'handler.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        PubVars.ServerStatus = e.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

I know I do not want to close the socket until all is sent but I am not sure what i am missing. I want to send the first file, then send back to the client a status update which all works well. Then when the client receives the status update, I want to send the next file and so on.

Android Code:

```
Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 11000);

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

            String FileName = "my.jpg";
            String FilePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydir/" + FileName;
            File f= new File(FilePath);
            byte[] data= readFileToByteArray(f);
            String strbase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            //I chose to pass the filename as part of my header string then parse it out on server
            output.println("<HEADER>" + FileName + "</HEADER>" + strbase64 + "<EOF>");
            output.flush();

            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                returnString.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            Log.i("INPUT",returnString.toString());
            //If true run the next one


            //SEND NEW FILE

            Log.i("NEXT","STARTING NEXT FILE");
            FileName = "my2.png";
            FilePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydir/" + FileName;
            f= new File(FilePath);
            data= readFileToByteArray(f);
            strbase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            output.println("<HEADER>" + FileName + "</HEADER>" + strbase64 + "<EOF>");
            output.flush();

            in = socket.getInputStream();

            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            returnString = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                returnString.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            Log.i("INPUT",returnString.toString());

            //END ANOTHER FILE




            output.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear about which socket you are talking. Its client-server isnt it?

Comment: Yes, the .Net is the server and the Android is the client. When I send once with the handler shutdown and handler close. All is good, I then send again. The problem is the socket is closing each time so I am trying to keep it open by the modifications I made in the .Net code. I think all is fine in Android as it runs through accept no InputStream return on second send and the server does not receive I believe due to the handler(socket) close. Again, works if I do once and invoke send again but that closes and opens socket each time. Seems inefficient to me. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: A lot of talking. I still dont know which socket is the problematic one. You are supposed to say 'the client socket` or 'the serversocket'  or `a clientsocket of the server`. Be clear please.

Comment: Server Socket is the Problem